# Suggestion: new tags for web technologies

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I tried to post a question...

*...why are they 'questions' if this site is primarily for code review requests?*

...anyway, the tags I tried to use did not exist and I don't have a high enough reputation to create them. These tags are:

[responsive-design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design), [media-queries](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media-queries) and either [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-review) or [review-request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-request) (or something else suitable).

If 'The Establishment' is willing, or if some other kind soul with a reputation high enough is able to create these tags it'd be much appreciated.

(actually whilst you're at it, a `suggestion` tag on here wouldn't go a miss either ;)

Comment: As @svick has noted, a tag for code-review or review-request doesn't make any sense. As for your other requested tags, you'll need to give us some indication of why you think they are needed.

Comment: I see your point about the 'code-review' tag. As for the others it's simply the case that they don't exist and I need to use them. I can't see how I can give a clear indication of the question's topic without them. It's just a clarification thing. I'm not saying that they *must* exist, just that for me on that particular question it would be useful.

Comment: The question is: what kind of questions would fit into your tags? Are there any existing questions that should have those tags? Will somebody really have a reason to look at all the media-query review questions? Tags only make sense if they are used more then a small number of times. Your tags don't *have* to give a complete description of your question, that's what your question is for.

Comment: While this wasn't the main topic of this post, I am quite intrigued by your first question: "Why are they 'questions' if this site is primarily for code review requests?" This is a good point. I believe changing allusions of "asking a question" to "requesting a review" would help relieve some of the inappropriate "questions" we are getting. They seem to be gradually increasing in frequency, which I think may have something to do with us not being as harsh as SO in this regard, but removing the ambiguity might just help.

Answer (score 3):

I think that having [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-review) or [review-request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-request) as tags doesn't make any sense on this site. What would be the purpose of a tag that should be on all questions on the site?

Regarding the other tags, AFAIK, tags can't be created independently, they have to be created by adding them to a specific question. So, if you think a tag would be suitable for a specific question, but you can't add it because it hasn't been created yet, post a question here on meta. Alternatively, you could flag the question for moderator attention, explaining that you think a tag should be added to it, but I'm not sure that would be appropriate (I'm not a moderator).