# Why are they 'questions' if this site is primarily for code review requests?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

["why are they 'questions' if this site is primarily for code review requests?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/592/suggestion-new-tags-for-web-technologies)

This is not originally my question, but it never-the-less is still a good one that deserves more attention. I'm sort of new to the whole meta thing, so I'm not sure if this question is on topic, but it seems like it should be. At the very least it could vaguely be associated with the site's design, #5 in the FAQ.

We are a site that focuses on reviews, yet we are still using "questions". Now, I don't know if this is possible, but I believe changing allusions of "asking a question" to "requesting a review" would help distinguish ourselves and relieve some of the "inappropriate questions" we are getting. I don't know about other sections, but in PHP we are getting an increasing number of posts like: "help me fix this broken code". Now, I'm sure we wont ever be able to fully prevent posts like this, and I think some of this may actually be because we are not as harsh as SO in stamping it out, but removing the ambiguity might help.

Comment: They are "Questions" because Stack Exchange originated as (and is still largely) a Q&A site and the term is baked into the software.

Comment: @GarethRees: True - perhaps we could at least change the UI text to read "Request A Review"?

Comment: Somehow related. Many questions are titled "How to improve this design?". How can I find the question that is relevant to my problem without opening it? How can we forse members to write more specific questions/titles?

Comment: @dzieciou: You mean like this [question right here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15960/comparing-multiple-fields-from-two-tables-looking-for-matches-updating-2nd-tab)? It went through at least four different names, all of which were very similar to the one you describe. This most recent one wasn't even the one that I remember it being changed to yesterday. If you look at the comments, you can see it was requested to be changed a few times. This is a really big issue.

Comment: Yes, but also titles like [How to improve this design?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15621/how-to-improve-this-design). Often adding one word is makes the job: [How to improve my *factory* design?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8041/how-to-improve-my-factory-design). I believe that would be easier to find and spot when searching for factory pattern issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We do not have the ability to display custom UI text on the individual SE sites. The developers could implement it, but that's up to them. Since we are the odd site out, I wouldn't hold my breath on them deciding its a good idea.

Comment: It was brought up on meta.stackoverflow.com ! http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155724/182974